# How to draw a QLineEdit in QTableView's QStyleItemDelegate using the paint function? Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: c++, qt

QStyleItemDelegate's paintEvent can't draw a QLineEdit. If I want to implement something like folder renaming, how to do??

Comment: Instead of painting a line edit yourself just create it (the object) in `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor()` function.

Comment: if use QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(),the QLineEdit will show when item set Qt::EditRole,but i  just want it show like QML's GridView.@vahancho